# How do I solve derivatives with really high powers in the definition of derivative formula?

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function, partial-derivative

Say I have function K(x,y).
$$
K_x = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{y[(x+h)(x+1)]^{2019} - y[x(x+h+1)]^{2019}}{h(x+1)^{2019}(x+h+1)^{2019}}
$$
Find $K_{xxyy}$ (basically differentiate $x$ one more time then $y$ two times).

I tried solving it normally and noticed how big this was getting and finally realized that's not the correct way of doing it. I was thinking of perhaps factoring but didn't know how to start it. I noticed the first part of the numerator is like $f(x+h) - f(x)$, and the bottom is like $h$ but with two extra terms. Honestly I don't know how to work it and would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Denote $c = 2019$ and $G(x,h) = [(x+h)(x+1)]^c - [x(x+h+1)]^c$ we have
$$K_x = \frac{y}{ (x+1)^c} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac1{(x+h+1)^c}\frac{ G(x,h)}{h}$$

Add and subtract two pairs of auxiliary terms to make three sets of $\Delta f = f(x+h) - f(x)$.
$$\begin{alignat}{2}
G(x,h) =  [(x+h)(x+1)]^c &  &{}- [x(x+1)]^c \\
&&{}+ [x(x+1)]^c  &&{}- [(x+h)(x+h+1)]^c\\
&& &&{}+ [(x+h)(x+h+1)]^c - [x(x+h+1)]^c \\
\end{alignat}$$
Or to emphasize the the structure of $f' = \lim \frac{\Delta f}h$ explicitly:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{ G(x,h) }h &= (x+1)^c \frac{(x+h)^c - x^c}h \\
& \hspace{24pt} + \frac{[(x+h)(x+1+h)]^c - [x(x+1)]^c}h \\
& \hspace{60pt} +  (x+h+1)^c \frac{(x+h)^c - x^c}h 
\end{align}$$
Put back the common factor $\frac1{(x+h+1)^c}$ and take the limits of the three sets separately. The first set will combine with the 3rd set.
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac1{(x+h+1)^c}\frac{ G(x,h) }h = \frac{\mathrm{d}x^c}{\mathrm{d}x} + \frac1{(x+1)}\frac{\mathrm{d}[x(x+1)]^c}{\mathrm{d}x} +\frac{\mathrm{d}x^c}{\mathrm{d}x}$$
Can you take it from here?

---

Note that $K_x$ is directly proportional to $y$ and so will $K_{xx}$ be. The double derivative with respect to $y$ will result zero $K_{xxyy} = 0$.

I have to assume that this is a typo in the question statement.

Anyway, the basic algebraic manipulation to formulate $f' = \lim \frac{\Delta f}h$ is demonstrated above. Please adapt accordingly after the typo involving $y$ is corrected.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Perhaps I have worded it wrong, but it is in fact a function with both x and y, a multivariable function. Kxxyy is partial derivative, so is Kx, perhaps my notation is different from what you are used to seeing. Kxxyy would mean differentiating with respect to x twice and with respect to y twice afterwards.

Comment: Hmm? My notation is exactly the same as yours. I don't see where your comment is coming from. Which part of my post is inconsistent with your question post?